# about C and eclipse - scanf

Tags: c, eclipse, scanf

When I try to use `scanf`

```
int main() {

    int x1,x2,x3,y1,y2,y3;

    printf("Enter 3 pairs of positive integers separated by spaces:\n");

    scanf("%u %u %u %u %u %u", &x1, &y1, &x2, &y2, &x3, &y3);
```

I get the program running, like for an input.
Then I put the input, but it prints the "enter 3 pairs..." and does nothing

why is that?

Comment: When you say it "does nothing", what exactly do you mean? Does it hang after you enter your 6 numbers? Or does it crash before you can enter them? Just to be clear: `scanf` expects input from standard input, so you have to actually input those 6 numbers for the program to progress.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you have to enter values; it is the goal of `scanf`.

By the way, your program contains an undefined behavior : `%u` mismatchs with `int` pointers. Use rather `%d`/`%i` format in `printf`. An other solution is to declare your variables as `unsigned int` type, to match with the `printf` format. Moreover, a part of your source code is missing.

Comment: %d or %i for signed integers. %u for unsigned :)

Comment: hmm @Kirilenko, your way of forming a sentence is slightly weird. :-) but correct none-the-less

Comment: I'm sorry, I am just 15, and not english at all. I guess my english is not very good.

Comment: :) For a 15 year old, you have a good reputation here, my friend. Keep up the good work :-)

Comment: @Kirilenko galgal has stated that he/she entered the input.

Comment: thanks first - i did mention - i putted for this program the input

for example - 1,2,3,4,5,6 - in the consule

but than he returned ""Enter 3 pairs of positive integers separated by spaces" and stopped>

something is wrong - i assumed it will ask for ""Enter 3 pairs of positive integers separated by spaces" and than i'll enter, it will put it in the x1,x2,x3... and than i can do more stuff with it..

Comment: Did you try `fflush(stdout)`? Eclipse terminal behave strangely.

Answer (score 1):

`%u` is unsigned integer. `%d` or `%i` is signed integers. Please take care of these `quirks` and `gotchas` in C. Be careful to oblige to correct format specifiers.

Comment: I agree that you should be careful with `%d` vs. `%u`, but I don't think that is actual problem here (an implementation would have to be very strange to behave differently for these cases as long as not-very-big positive numbers are entered. I think the problem is that the user doesn't understand that the program is waiting for input from him, and that's why it isn't doing anything.

Answer (score 0):

You might find it more convenient to use `fgets` instead of `scanf`.  The eclipse terminal is a little funky.

Refer to this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1897227/problem-with-scanf-in-eclipse-minigw)