# Issues with a program farenh ---> celsius

Tags: c

I just started learning C.

I tried a code from a book and copied it exactly to Eclipse. However, I prompt is not displayed.

```
// The program compute celsius degrees
// from farenheit

#include <stdio.h>

#define CONVERSION (5.0f / 9.0f)
#define FREEZING_POINT 32.0f


int main(void){

    float fahrenheit, celsius;

    printf("Enter fahrenheit temperature: ");
    scanf("%f", &fahrenheit);

    celsius = (fahrenheit - FREEZING_POINT) * CONVERSION; 

    printf("Celsius equivalent: %.1f\n", celsius);


    return 0;
}
```

What is the problem?

Comment: Strange. Now error is gone but prompt to enter a number is not displayed

Answer (score 0):

Basically as is written here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/1897232/1430586
you need to add this after the printf:

```
fflush(stdout);
```

This is only required for Eclipse, if you were to run the executable file directly it would probably work without this.

Another thing i can think of, if the program terminates as soon as you run it